# E_PARSE and error_reporting

Tags: php

From the manual:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

If E_PARSE it's a compile time error does it make sense to use it in error_reporting function?

Take this script for example:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_PARSE);
x = 1;
```

The parse error will still be displayed if php.ini activated it.

Answer (score 1):

In case there are parse errors in included files:

```
<?php /* good.php */
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_PARSE);
include 'bad.php';
?>

<?php /* bad.php */
z = 1;
?>
```

This is probably also for consistency with ini settings that would disable error reporting of `E_PARSE`.